# Changing the default directory structure

Tags: linux, unix, directory-structure, linux-from-scratch, distro

If I start a new distro (e.g. [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/)):

1. How can I change the directory structure?
2. What should I expect after it's ready? (probably can't install most of the packages without modification, right?

But, before you down vote: I've been asked to make a new distro for a specific project which they need (actually, want) a new directory structure with a few changes, for example remove the `var` and `bin` directories, but without halting the system. The application of this distro is so limited, so i think it shouldn't be a big deal as they need just a few packages to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are few pointers that come to my mind and definitely it is not complete:

1. Your `PATH` should be updated in the startup scripts like `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile.d`, and so on to reflect the updated directories.
2. Configuration files tend to use `/var` quite often. (`/var/log`, `/var/tmp`) You'd need to modify all these location references.
3. Basically your kernel is going to start `/sbin/init` which is going to start the initialization at `/etc/rc.d` or equivalent. If you start tracing all the scripts and services invoked in these startup scripts, I believe you should be able to capture all the places you'd need to modify the path names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also pointing out the `/sbin/init` and `/etc/rc.d`, that should be a nice start! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can create a folder called system and the move all the files into the `/system` folder. and after that create symlinks, so the system can still be used. example:

`su -i`

`cd /`

`mkdir system`

`mv /usr /system/usr`

`ln -s /system/usr /usr`

I just did it........it broke my system XD (i think it was because i moved all the files into `/system` , including `/boot` witch is used by GRUB)

The chance of breaking the system is huge if you don't have background knowledge. Example if you move `/bin` to `/system/bin`, then you won't be able to create the symlink afterwards because the `ln` command (which is a program) is located in the `/bin` folder so moving it will end up in an error.

also, check out [gobolinux.org](http://www.gobolinux.org) which is based around what i just did. The entire system has been reorganized and to maintain compatibility, they have created symlinks so that they don't have to reprogram an app when porting applications.